# TSQL local variables seem not to be populated immediately after selecting into them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a MS SQL Server script in which I create a temporary stored procedure that, when passed two patient identifiers, selects and prints details from the second patient.  It then uses those identifiers and details to call another stored procedure to merge those two patients together.

This script runs perfectly on several test databases here, but when I ran the same script at a busy site, it appeared as though the local variables I was selecting those patient details into were 'occasionally' not being populated in time for the PRINT, but the subsequent EXEC of the merge procedure always had them populated just fine.  Most of the time, the PRINT showed those values correctly.

Here is a trimmed down version of what I'm doing.  What do you think?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TMP_MergeMRNs] @Merge_From_Medical_Record_Number VARCHAR(64) = NULL,
                                       @Merge_From_Institution_Name      VARCHAR(64) = NULL,
                                       @Merge_To_Medical_Record_Number   VARCHAR(64) = NULL,
                                       @Merge_To_Institution_Name        VARCHAR(64) = NULL
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW

      /* ALL parameters must be supplied */
      IF @Merge_From_Medical_Record_Number IS NULL
          OR @Merge_From_Institution_Name IS NULL
          OR @Merge_To_Medical_Record_Number IS NULL
          OR @Merge_To_Institution_Name IS NULL
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'ERROR. One or more of the 4 required fields was empty.'

            RETURN 4
        END

      /* Retrieve the merge_to patient demographics */
      DECLARE @lstNm  NVARCHAR(64),
              @frstNm NVARCHAR(64),
              @mdlNm  NVARCHAR(64)

      SELECT @lstNm = id1.LastName,
             @frstNm = id1.FirstName,
             @mdlNm = id1.MiddleName
      FROM   [dbo].[PATIENT] pid1
             INNER JOIN [dbo].[INSTITUTION] i1
               ON pid1.InstitutionDBKey = i1.InstitutionDBKey
      WHERE  i1.InstitutionName = @Merge_To_Institution_Name
             AND pid1.MedicalRecordNumber = @Merge_To_Medical_Record_Number

      PRINT LTrim('Merge From Patient: ' + RTrim(@Merge_From_Medical_Record_Number)) + ' / ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@Merge_From_Institution_Name))

      PRINT LTrim('Merge To Patient: ' + RTrim(@Merge_To_Medical_Record_Number)) + ' / ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@Merge_To_Institution_Name))

      PRINT '  Name: ' + ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@lstNm)), '') + IsNull(', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@frstNm)), '') + IsNull(' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@mdlNm)), '')

      EXEC PatientMerge
        @Merge_From_Medical_Record_Number,
        @Merge_From_Institution_Name,
        @Merge_To_Medical_Record_Number,
        @Merge_To_Institution_Name,
        /* last */ @lstNm,
        /* first */ @frstNm,
        /* middle */ @mdlNm

      RETURN 0
  END

GO
```

Comment: Your analysis definitely isn't correct. There is no time delay for assignment. If they are `NULL` nothing will be printed as concatenating `NULL` yields `NULL`

Comment: I agree Martin.  Those variables must have had something in them.  Just trying to describe what I saw.  The PRINT statement sometimes would show nothing for the local variables, but the stored procedure call right after the PRINT always had values in those variables.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're seeing?  I assume you're talking about the @xxxNm variables.  What does your PRINT output look like, and what do you think was passed to PatientMerge?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting this '@variable (type) = null' then wanting to force a value?  Why not just remove the '= null' portion and it will REQUIRE a user to put in a value?  EG: If I do create ... (@var int = Null) it tells the proc it ACCEPTS NULLS and can put in null values as input.  If you do the default of create .... (@var int) it REQUIRES a value on input.  You are overriding the default and then re declaring the default.  I don't see why you are doing this.

If you set the default behavior to be requiring non nulls the proc will fail unless the variables are listed for it, which is what you want it appears.

As for the proc sometimes working and sometimes not I would think that you maybe should set defaults on input variables if they are null.

```
-- Method 1 set a default if variable is null
declare @int int;

select @int = isnull(@int, 2);  -- variable not listed, no problem ensure there is a default or else do not more forward

select @Int
GO

-- Method 2, do not move forward if variable is null
declare @int int;

If @int is not null
BEGIN
  select @Int;
END
ELSE 
    Select 'Variable is null, please identify value if you wish system to proceed'
```